# android.widget.DayPickerView is not access on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker

I'm trying to update my app on Android Marshmallow.

I've got a `Dialog` with a `DatePicker` and a `TimePicker` in it :

```
             <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/new_task_date_picker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:calendarViewShown="false"
                android:background="@color/gray_overlay"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_normal"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_normal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_large" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/new_task_hour"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_normal" />

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/new_task_time_picker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:timePickerMode="spinner"
                android:background="@color/gray_overlay" />
```

It's working on android 5 but when I test it on a device that got android 6 I get this error when i'm trying to inflate my dialog:

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #116: Binary XML file line #116: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                 at com.ikomobi.alptis.main.task.NewTaskDialogFragment.onCreateView(NewTaskDialogFragment.java:80)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #116: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                 at com.ikomobi.alptis.main.task.NewTaskDialogFragment.onCreateView(NewTaskDialogFragment.java:80) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                 at com.ikomobi.alptis.main.task.NewTaskDialogFragment.onCreateView(NewTaskDialogFragment.java:80) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.widget.DayPickerView
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.<init>(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:118)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePicker.createCalendarUIDelegate(DatePicker.java:160)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:140)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:126)
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:122)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                 at com.ikomobi.alptis.main.task.NewTaskDialogFragment.onCreateView(NewTaskDialogFragment.java:80) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.widget.DayPickerView
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.<init>(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:118) 
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePicker.createCalendarUIDelegate(DatePicker.java:160) 
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:140) 
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:126) 
                                                                 at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:122) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                 at com.ikomobi.alptis.main.task.NewTaskDialogFragment.onCreateView(NewTaskDialogFragment.java:80) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<android.widget.DayPickerView> is not access
```

and my app crashes.

My application has all the autorisation granted and I don't understand what's happening, do you have any ideas ?

EDIT:

it's actually a dialogFragment, I should have precise it...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line:

```
android:spinnersShown="true"
```

after this one:

```
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

EDIT: this is my code in onCreate of the dialog:

```
public class DateTimeDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.datetimedialog);
```

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/fragstyle"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/please_select"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDlgHead"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        style="@style/text" />

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:spinnersShown="true"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner" />

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK"
            android:id="@+id/btnclosedialog"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:id="@+id/btncanceldialog"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it's actually a dialogfragment, and i already request FEATURE_NO_TITLE on the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Just using this constructor:

```
public DatePickerDialog(Context context, int themeResId, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

instead of:

```
public DatePickerDialog(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
```

works for me.